# How to get the latest data from parent to child components after page refresh

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I am working on a project and using `Vue.js` for the frontend. I have following code in the `main.js` file.

```
new Vue({ // eslint-disable-line no-new
      //el: '#app',
router,
 data () {
  return {
      friends: []
  }
},
methods: {
    getFriends: function () {
        return this.friends;
    }
},
created: function () {
    this.$http.get('/user/' + this.getUserIDCookie('userID') +
        '/friends').then(function (response) {
        this.friends = response.data;
    });
},
components: {
    'nav-bar': require('./components/Navigation.vue')
},
template: `
    <div id="app">
        <nav-bar></nav-bar>
        <router-view class="router-view"></router-view>
    </div>`
}).$mount('#app');
```

In one of the pages(for ex. when the page is redirected to `localhost/#/user/1/details`, I am retrieving the friends' list from `main.js` like below:

```
<script type="text/babel">
export default {
    name: 'profile',
    data: function () {
        return {
            user: {},
            friends: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
        // Some methods
    },
    created: function () {
        this.friends = this.$root.getFriends();
    }
}
</script>
```

The problem arises when I refresh the current page. After page refresh, `this.friends` is null/undefined because `this.$root.getFriends()` is returning null/undefined. I can move it to `user` component, but I want to keep it in `main.js` so that `GET` call is used once and data will be available to the whole application.

Any input regarding how to solve this issue would be great. I am using Vue 2.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really, what you want to do, is pass the data the component needs as props.

The dirt simple easiest way to do it is this.

```
<router-view class="router-view" :friends="friends"></router-view>
```

And in your profile component,

```
export default {
    props:["friends"],
    name: 'profile',
    data: function () {
        return {
            user: {},
            friends: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
        // Some methods
    }
}
```

If you want to get more sophisticated, the later versions of VueRouter allow you to [pass properties to routes](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/passing-props.html) in several ways.

Finally, there's always Vuex or some other state management tool if your application gets complex enough.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This way I could have used if there was only one list to pass. But there are several like that. So I was wondering if there is any other way. I will look into your suggestions. Thanks mate.

Comment: @Pradeepb You can pass as many lists as you want. The component will only use the ones you define in it's `props`.

Comment: Thanks. It works as expected now. But I found it bit tedious since, I have to pass each time for first-child, second-child and so on(wherever I want to have this data).

Comment: @Pradeepb Then you probably want to look at a global data store or state management option.

Comment: yep. I will have to explore on that now. Thanks for the suggestions and your time :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you refresh the page, the whole app reloads, which includes the `get`, which is asynchronous. The router figures out that it needs to render `details`, so that component loads, and calls `getFriends`, but the asynchronous `get` hasn't finished.

You *could* work around this by saving and pulling the Promise from the `get`, but Bert's answer is correct: the Vue Way is to send data as props, not to have children pull it from parents.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying :)